Why does $\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}\ e^{-Q(x,y)}\ dxdy=\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}d^2\hat{x}\ e^{-\lambda_1 \hat{\mathbf{x}_1}-\lambda_1 \hat{\mathbf{x}_2}}$?
Mi teacher wrote the following:
$$\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}\ e^{-(5x^2-4xy+5y^2)}\ dxdy=\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}d^2\hat{x}\ e^{-\lambda_1 \hat{\mathbf{x}_1}-\lambda_1 \hat{\mathbf{x}_2}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{21}}$$
Where $5x^2-4xy+5y^2$ may be written as $\mathbf{x}^t $$\begin{bmatrix}
5&-2 \\
-2 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$$\ \mathbf{x}$.
Then he said that $\hat{\mathbf{x}}=P^{-1}\mathbf{x}$, where $P^{-1}P=I$.
He simplified the first expression with the following operations:
$$\mathbf{x}^tA\mathbf{x}=\hat{\mathbf{x}}P^tAP\mathbf{x}=\lambda_1 \hat{\mathbf{x}_1}-\lambda_1 \hat{\mathbf{x}_2}$$
I understand this, what I do not get is the following reasoning:
$$d^2\hat{x} =Jd^2x=det(P^{-1})d^2x$$
Where do $J$ and $d^2x$ come from?

This is called change of variables formula.

@SangchulLee so $J$ is just the Jacobian?

Yes, indeed. :)
